# List of command-line compressors

Tags: command-line, compression, 7zip

I am making a list of command-line compressors, So far i only found 2.

1. 7-zip (7za.exe)
2. UHARC (uharc.exe)

Please list only free compressors :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: blatantly off topic, has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- compress (zlib)
- gzip
- zip
- rar
- jar
- bzip2

Will add others as I think of them :)